# Getting 2 inputs from command line in Bison/Flex

Tags: c++, command-line, user-input, bison

I have a simple language parser using Bison/Flex and I want to read in two separate numbers from the command line which looks like: ./compile < sample.txt 4 7

I have it reading in the inputs from main and saving them to an array. As far as I can tell that part is working fine, where I am having trouble is when I try save the input (and the name of the input) and I am trying to put them in an unsorted map, but I can only figure out how to do one input, but then can't get to the other input.

I tried saving the input into a vector and then removing the top item to save into the map, but the compiler has a problem with the vector as it says it can't convert vector into a double (I can't figure out why a trying to remove a double from a vector would return a vector)

This is probably because I'm not too familiar with Bison/Flex yet and I haven't done much with C++ is several years so I'm sorry if the solution is obvious. I've been looking around for an answer for about a day now but can't find anything. Please let me know if you can help me out.

This is the main:
[image]

and this is were it needs to save each input from the command line with the type 'parameter:'
[image]

I tried several ways (list, stack, array) but so far the only way that doesn't cause an error is the array like: ***parameter: INDENTIFIER ':' type {symbols.insert($1, params[0]);} ;***
But obviously this will only give one of the inputs (as it's only accessing the first part of the array) what can I do to add more than one input?
This is the class for Symbols where the function insert() is. It needs to save each Identifier and input in the map. Thank you for the help.
[image]

Comment: Please include your code as text, not as images, and include a complete program (see the help section on making a [mcve]). When reporting compiler errors, quote the exact error (by copy and paste), including the line number where the error was reported. Without a precise problem description, trying to answer the question is an exercise in speculation. Thanks.

Comment: Also, the tag for the Flex scanner generator is [tag:flex-lexer], but it should only be applied to a question about a generated scanner. As a rule of thumb, if you don't feel it necessary to include anything from your `.l` file, your question probably has nothing to do with Flex.

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel silly. I was just assuming a function like list.pop_front(); would return the value stored there. I looked at the reference and found I was wrong. So I got it working using a list. I'm so sorry to waste everyone's time.
I added this to fix it:

```
list<double> params;
parameter:
    IDENTIFIER ':' type { if(!params.empty) {
                              input = params.front();
                              params.pop_front();
                          }
                          symbols.insert($1, input); } ;
```

Just out of curiosity though how would one go about doing it using a dynamic array??

Such as initializing *params* as:

```
double *params;

parameter:
    IDENTIFIER ':' type {symbols.insert($1, params[??]);} ;
```